# how to fix Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets

Tags: wordpress

im having trouble in solving this error please help me im just new to civicrm

my goal is to update and view the data that store in civicrm database
im using wordpress

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE!  What are you doing that results in this error?  Is this a new installation?  Is this an existing one that you're upgrading?  What CiviCRM versions is this? What version of php are you using?

Comment: im using wordpress 6.1.1, CIVICRM 5.56.1 and php 8.1.10 and this extension sir i new i've created this extension im new to civicrm

Comment: OK, so explain what you're trying to do - there are lots of existing ways to view & update data so you may not need to create your own extension.  Also, if you include a link to a github repo or similar with your code, someone might help diagnose the problem.